# remove first part of a variable in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm creating a text file containing HDD info pulled from hdparm in Linux. I'm then reading that file back and picking out certain lines and storing them in variables for later use. I want to remove all white space and remove the first part of each line just leaving the information like so:

```
Model Number:       ST9500325AS
```

Will become:

```
ST9500325AS
```

So far I have the following:

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

# Get HDD details and save them to hdd_info.txt
info = Popen(["sudo", "hdparm", "-I", "/dev/sda1"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = info.stdout.read()
f = open('hdd_info.txt', 'w')
f.write(output)
f.close()

# Get HDD info as vars
with open('hdd_info.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.readlines()

model = data[4].strip()
print model
```

Now it removed the whitespace from the beginning but doesn't remove the whitespace in the middle. Also trying to remove the 'Model Number:' part of the variable I've tried the following but without success:

```
model.lstrip('13')
```

Comment: simple typo error in the title, thank you for your constructive feedback

Comment: It looks like you could just search for 'Model Number:' and then strip the whitespaces

Comment: why the vote down? What am I missing from the question that you need?

Comment: I didn't downvote, there is a single close vote for 'unclear what you are asking', I don't have a problem with this question, it's pretty clear to me. You could probably just include the bits of code that are relevant as this is just a string parsing exercise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split it by colon, get the second item from the resulted list and strip all the whitespaces:

```
split(':', 1)[-1].strip()
```

Comment: You need to limit the split, or risk splitting the field *value* too. What if the field has a IPv6 address for example?

Comment: Switch to `[-1]` rather than `[1]`; that way it'll work even if there is no `':'` in the input string.

Comment: aha, I certainly missed that. adding it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to chop off the first 13 characters of a string, you can do this:

```
text = text[13:]
```

Or, if the unwanted stuff at the start of your line is of variable length (as picked out by Martijn Pieters), you could go from the index of the colon.

```
text = text[text.index(':')+1:]
```

After which the space would be at the beginning, so you could call

```
text = text.strip()
```

to strip off the surrounding whitespace.

Comment: Hardcoding the index is not a good idea; you are assuming that there are only `Model Number:` fields.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> m = "Model Number:       ST9500325AS"
>>> m.split(':')[1].strip()
'ST9500325AS'
```